# Analytical solution to $1-x=k\ln(x)$

Tags: logarithms, lambert-w

Find an analytical  **real** solution to $1-x=k\ln(x)$, in which $k$ is real and $x\ne 1$.

I notice that (please correct if I am wrong):

1. when $k>=0$, we have only one real solution of $x=1 \Rightarrow k<0 \Rightarrow x>1$
2. when $x>1$, both $1-x$ and $k\ln(x)$ are motonically decreasing. As $1-x$ is a straight line and $k\ln(x)$ is convex in shape, $x$ has **only one** real solution.

I know it is possible to solve it with numerical approximation; is anyone aware of any analytical solution?

P.S. I tried to apply Lambert w function on both sides but it returns $x=1$.

Comment: $$x=k W\left(\frac{e^{1/k}}{k}\right)$$

Comment: thanks for the response! Now I realised I forgot to output the larger solution when I apply lambertw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Find an analytical real solution to \begin{align}1-x&=k\ln(x)\tag{1}\label{1} \end{align} , in which $k$ is real and $x\ne1$.

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}$

For $x\ne1$
we can rewrite \eqref{1} as

\begin{align}
\frac{\ln(x)}{1-x}
&=
\frac1k
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
 \end{align}

Note that LHS of \eqref{1} is negative for all real $x>0,\ x\ne 1$,
and the known unique real solution for $k<0$ is:

\begin{align}
x&=
\begin{cases}
k\Wp\Big(\tfrac1k\,\exp(\tfrac1k)\Big)
,\quad k\in(-1,0)
,\\
k\Wm\Big(\tfrac1k\,\exp(\tfrac1k)\Big)
,\quad k\in(-\infty,-1)
\tag{3}\label{3}
,
\end{cases}
\end{align}

where $\Wp$ is the principal branch
and $\Wm$ is the other real branch
of the Lambert $\W$ function.

$\endgroup$